# Finding How Many Slices of the Largest Square from a L * B Piece of Bread I Can Make

Tags: java, math, square-root

So I am working on a hackerRank challenge in which the input is the L and B of a piece of bread and the  output is supposed to be the amount of perfect square slices (no residual) I can get.

> Martha is interviewing at Subway. One of the rounds of the interview requires her to cut a bread of size l * b into smaller identical pieces such that each piece is a square having maximum possible side length with no left over piece of bread.

I feel that my code does the job yet I keep getting errors. Since I can't see what is wrong with it I was hoping for someone to help me point out where I gone wrong.

My code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Solution {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
    Scanner STDIN = new Scanner(System.in);
    int l = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int count = STDIN.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i<count; i++){
        l = STDIN.nextInt();
        b = STDIN.nextInt(); 

        if(l>b){
            check(l,b);
        }
        else if(b>l){
            check(l,b);
        }
        else{
            check(l,b);
        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
}

public static boolean square (int n){
    int sqrt = (int) Math.sqrt(n);
    if(sqrt*sqrt == n){
        return true;    
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
public static void check(int first, int second){
    int mult = first*second;

    if(square(first)){
    System.out.print(second);            
    }
    else if(square(second)){
    System.out.print(first);             
    }
    else{
    factors(mult);   
    }    
}
public static void factors(int n){
    //int B = 0;
    //int A = 0;

    for(int i = 1; i<=n; i++){
        if(n%i == 0){            

            if(square((n/i))){
                     System.out.print((i));
                     break;                    
            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Immediately I see that the section if(l>b){
            check(l,b);
        }
        else if(b>l){
            check(l,b);
        }
        else{
            check(l,b);
        } always resolves to check(l, b) no matter what. That might be the root of the issue.

Comment: @BlakeHood a copy / paste / *no thinking* problem indeed.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand the problem: you're given a rectangle of dimensions `l` and `b`, and asked to cut it such that the pieces are all squares of equal and maximized side length (and there are no remnants)? If that's right, are we talking integer lengths or fractional lengths (i.e. I assume `l` and `b` are integers, but could the side lengths of the squares produced be e.g. 1.5)?

Comment: The issue was that I wasn't thinking on "real life" terms. I can't paste a piece of bread together after cutting it up into pieces. @BlakeHood is definitely right, however, I need to rethink the process instead of just copy/paste the problem towards a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Find GCD of l and b. Then number of pieces = (l/gcd) * (b/gcd)

for(int j=1; j <= l && j <= b; ++j)
        {

```
    if(l%j==0 && b%j==0)
        gcd = j;
     }
     printf("%d\n",(l/gcd)*(b/gcd));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for the solution of the above problem:

```
package subway;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MarthaProblem {
    public static void main(String[] nag){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=0;i<t;i++){
            if(t>=1 && t<=1000){
                int l = sc.nextInt();
                int b = sc.nextInt();
                if((l>=1 && l<=1000)&&(b>=1 && b<=1000)){
                    System.out.println(calculate(l,b));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static int calculate(int l, int b){
        return ((l/(gcd(l,b)))*(b/(gcd(l,b))));
    }

    public static int gcd(int l,int b){
        if(b==0){
            return l;
        }else{
            return gcd(b, l%b);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I replied very late to this post, my solution may or not be required. But, this will be a reference and help to some one.

Comment: This solution is for finding the Martha is interviewing at Subway. Finding the maximum value of possible side length with no left over piece of bread.

Comment: Sorry for not providing the complete info in my previous comment. This is my first solution post in stack overflow. If i made any mistake, please let me know. GCD helps to find the number of possible side but we have to find the maximum value of possible side. So, i have made the program (l/(GCD)*b/(GCD)).